# How should you access the stack trace returned in the array of objects from Promise.allSettled() in addition to the error message?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

Promise.allSettled() returns an array of objects with statuses fulfilled or rejected and the reason, eg: '[{status: 'rejected', reason: 'Error: some error message}, ...]'

If you console.log the error out you can see both the reason and the stack trace. However when you save output to a log file you simply see the reason and not the full stack trace. How do you also save the stack trace?

Comment: As far as I can tell this question wasn't on stack overflow already and I am sure will help someone (like me) save some time trying to resolve. I am sure there is a reason if someone feels like down-voting a question, but a brief comment to explain would also be much appreciated so I can ensure I follow correct guidelines in future? If you could please take a moment to explain the down vote that would be very much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason gives you the error message. For full stack trace use reason.stack as below. The example here is batching a large number of promises so as not to run out of memory, with the stack trace also saved:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const batch = async myArr => {
    const res = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < myArr.length; i += 2) {
        const requests = myArr.slice(i, i + 2).map(num => {
            if (num % 2 === 0) {
                return Promise.resolve(num);
            }

            if (num % 2 === 1) {
                return Promise.reject(Error(`Rejected promise in for loop at num ${ num }`));
            }
        });

        // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
        await Promise.allSettled(requests)
            .then(response => res.push(response));
    }

    return res.flat();
};

batch([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    .then(res => {
        let failed = [];

        failed = res.filter(re => (re.status === 'rejected'));

        for (let i = 0; i < failed.length; i += 1) {
            fs.appendFileSync('reasons.txt', `${ failed[i].reason }\n`);
            fs.appendFileSync('stack-traces.txt', `${ failed[i].reason.stack }\n`);
        }
    });
```